# Como pegar id da sessão do PHP com jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Sabe o códigozinho que o PHP gera, que é o `PHPSESSID`?

Queria saber se tem como eu pegar esse value com jQuery e armazenar numa variável JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Eu gosto geralmente de fazer as coisas de maneira elegante.  Não gosto muito da ideia de misturar Javascript com PHP. Eu faria uma rota (ou página) para retornar um `JSON` contendo todas as informações necessárias para ser capturada pelo Javascript e capturaria isso via requisição Ajax.

No arquivo `sess_id.php`, faça:

```
session_start();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = json_encode(['session_id' => session_id()]);

exit($json);
```

No seu arquivo Javascript.

```
 function processarIDSessao(id) {

     // faz alguma coisa com o id da sessão aqui

     console.log(id);
 }

 $.getJSON('sess_id.php', function (response) {
     processarIDSessao(response.session_id);
 });
```

As vantagens de se fazer isso através da separação de camadas é que você não precisa depender de ter o Javascript sendo escrito direto no seu script PHP. Você poderia usar até um Javascript externo nesse caso.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize essa função JavaScript para buscar o ID da sessão com base em expressão regular:

```
function session_id() {
    return /PHPSESSID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}
```

Ou se você preferir criar e associar direto a uma variável

```
var session_id = /PHPSESSID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
```

Ou ainda do jeito antigo com PHP:

```
session_start(); 
$session = session_id(); 

echo "<script language='javascript'>  
var session_id = '$session';  
</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca ele como valor de um input e depois pega com o jQuery.

no HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="valor" value="<?=$valor?>" />
```

no jQuery:

```
var valor = $('#valor').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça um document.cookie; e de um split nele, depois é só pegar a posição exemplo, saida do document.cookie "wp-settings-1=mfold%3Do%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dtinymce; wp-settings-time-1=1512653710; _ga=GA1.2.1763768758.1508751393; _gid=GA1.2.2049773337.1512986621; __zlcmid=j4gpfmcsgyFXDD; PHPSESSID=locvlk4vha1037ivs5dcc1irg5"

como eles vem como um ponto e virgula eu só faço um split no ponto e virgula como o código abaixo, eles serão transformados em array, cada parte do ponto e virgula

```
var essid = document.cookie;
essid = essid.split(";");
```

isso irá me retornar um array

```
0:"wp-settings-1=mfold%3Do%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dtinymce"
1:" wp-settings-time-1=1512653710"
2:" _ga=GA1.2.1763768758.1508751393"
3:" _gid=GA1.2.2049773337.1512986621"
4:" __zlcmid=j4gpfmcsgyFXDD"
5:" PHPSESSID=locvlk4vha1037ivs5dcc1irg5"
length:6
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Agora é só eu usar a posição 5 da variavel

```
console.log(essid[5]);
```